# How to instruct SASS compiled via compass to ignore parsing a CSS hack

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I have a piece of CSS (a media query breakpoint) that is used to target IE8+. Problem is, when compass compiles the SASS it throws an error, which prevents the CSS from being output, even though the CSS hack is valid and works when it finally does run in a browser (I've tested it manually by doctoring the compass generated CSS file concerned.)

Is there a SASS command that can instruct compass to ignore/escape a designated CSS/SASS style?

Many thanks

Comment: use hacks mixin - http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/utilities/general/hacks/

Comment: Could you provide an example of the CSS hack that's causing the error?

Comment: @hopper: I'm targetting IE 8, 9, and 10 within a breakpoint using the following. Compass throws an error due to the 'screen\0' part. Without the breakpoint ('(max-width: 20em)') it compiles fine.

`@media screen\0 and (max-width: 20em) { padding: 1em 2em; }`

Comment: For some reason, I highly doubt that IE10 needs special rules applied to it.  Have you considered verifying that a hack is actually necessary in the first place?

Comment: @cimmanon : IE 10, 9 and 8 don't respect the same select box padding rules as Firefox, and I've tried everything to use one set of select box styles. The only way to remedy the situation is to provide different padding for IE. IE has a problem calculating EM untis it seems. Even IE10 hasn't got it right.

Comment: You can see the top and bottom padding differences between FF anf IE here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_Hug/93rSg/)

Comment: I don't understand what you think is the problem.  I don't have IE10, but http://netrenderer.com/ is showing IE10 renders identically to IE11 except for a 1px difference in vertical alignment.  Also, your demo isn't even using em.

Comment: The demo isn't mine. I borrowed it from another post. I'm on Windows 7, testing on the latest version of FF and IE10, and trust me, IE requires seperate styles for defining the padding within select boxes.

The task I'm trying  to achieve, regardless of what styles are applied, is to target IE BUT within a responsive breakpoint (i.e. 'max-width: 20em'). My hack otherwise works outside a breakpoint, but is ignored within.

Thanks for your time.